# Jquery changing table row color

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I am given this HTML file with a table structure in this way:

```
<table width="707" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="code"> First </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="code"> Second </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="code"> Third </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 2 </td>
  </tr>
```

I am not suppose to change anything on this HTML file.

I am to use Jquery to change the "First" row to other color when mouseover or hover. The code will be placed into a .js file which will be link to the HTML file.

So far I have done this:

```
$(".code").hover(function () {
$(this).css("background-color", "#333");
}, function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "");

    });
```

The problem is, I can only change the first column when I hover over, which is what the script is coded to do.

I have the option to change the .CSS file or the .js file.

How do I change the color of the whole row without changing anything in the HTML file?

Comment: Tried with `<tr class="code">` instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use CSS3, you can reference the "first" row (which is actually the second in your example) with :nth-child(2).  So your hover would work like this:

```css
tr:nth-child(2):hover {background:#333;}
```

```html
<table width="707" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="code"> First </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="code"> Second </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="code"> Third </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.

With the answer I got, I modified a little bit more.

In the .CSS file, I added:

```
tr:nth-child(first){
background-color:#4186BE
}
tr:nth-child(odd){
background-color:#009BE6
}
tr:nth-child(even){
background-color:#F96
}
```

In the .js file, I used the code given by dwreck08:

```
$(".code").hover(function () {
$(this).parent('tr').css("background-color", "#333");
}, function () {
$(this).parent('tr').css("background-color", "");
});
```

And there, I have the row in alternate colors. When mouse hover on the row with class code, the rows and column change color to under the .hover function.

Thank you guys for giving me a head start.

Appreciate all the help!!